# Oracle 11g Performance of Join

Tags: sql, oracle

I was doing some random testing on oracle 11g, and realized a strange performance difference between different JOIN using SQL developer.

I inserted 200,000 records into RANDOM_TABLE, and about 300 in unrelated_table, then run the two query for 10 times, the time stated is an average.

The two tables are totally unrelated, so the first one should give the same result as the second one, and indeed the row counts are the same.

```
1.  SELECT * FROM some_random_table t1 LEFT JOIN unrelated_table t2 ON 1=1;
~0.005 seconds to fetch the first 50 row.

2.  SELECT * FROM some_random_table t1 RIGHT JOIN unrelated_table t2 ON 1=1;
>0.05 seconds to fetch the first 50 row.

1.  SELECT * FROM some_random_table t1 FULL JOIN unrelated_table t2 ON 1=1;
~0.005 seconds to fetch the first 50 row.

2.  SELECT * FROM some_random_table t1 CROSS JOIN unrelated_table t2;
>0.05 seconds to fetch the first 50 row.
```

Can anyone explain the difference between these queries? Why are some faster and some slower by an order of magnitude?

Comment: just wondering what will happen if you replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT count(*)`?

Comment: What are the query plans?  Are you sure that the performance differences are repeatable and not the result of cache-related differences?  And are you sure that the time required to return the first 50 rows is the metric you really care about?  Most of the time, people are interested in the time it takes the query to finish running, not the time required to get the first few rows.

Comment: @cha Basically all takes ~0.26s to count 7M rows, looks like the LEFT and FULL join can obtain a partial result quicker.

Comment: that is why you should not rely on the partial result figures

Comment: Running these statements with the GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS hint will probably provide some enlightening information.  See https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_do_i_know_if